# How to Disable Laravel Php Unit Test in Production

Tags: laravel, phpunit

In Laravel below 5.6 there is option to remote code execution, remote code execution run by the phpunit test to avoid that, i want to know how to remove on production

Answer (score 1):

If all your tests inherit from the base TestCase then you could always over-ride the setUp method  Something like :

```php
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'testing') {
           throw new \Exception('Argh!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: `base TestCase` in  `TestCase.php`

Answer (score 0):

I pushed Paul's solution a little further to prevent test execution if env is not pointing to the local_db Docker container. Which should also prevent execution in production. Multi-schema version. Prevents accidental refresh.

```
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        collect(['DB_HOST', 'DB2_HOST', 'DB3_HOST'])->each(function ($db) {
            if (env($db) !== 'local_db') {
                throw new \Exception( "$db Must use Local DB for testing!");
            }
        });
    }
```